# Why does output redirection not work in this case?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

OS is `ubuntu12.04`. I wrote a python program `main.py`, and wanted to run it easily. So I created the following shell script called `run.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

python main.py & >/dev/null  2>&1
```

And executed this command `chmod u+x run.sh`.

However, when I `./run.sh`, the python program's output is still there in the terminal.
But this can work: `./run.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`. But this way is against my original intention, since it's too complex to use.

I wonder why this could happen. And how can I achieve my intention?

Comment: What do you mean by "run it easily"? Run it in background? Discard any output/error text? Both of these? Something else?

Comment: @MarcoS Both of these.

Comment: Then both the answers you received are the solution. Please accept one, or explain why not... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run script at the background try this:

```
python main.py >/dev/null  2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in between `&` and `>/dev/null`, so the Python process gets run in the background without the output redirection applying to it.  If you remove the `&` there will be no output.  It's also enough to remove the space since `&>` is valid bash, but you probably didn't mean that.

Comment: What is the meaning of `&>` ?